# Chasing the wrong man or chasing the wrong men?

Tags: harry-potter

According to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/261802/31394) and the comments on it, there are two different versions of the sentence from *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* that the linked question is asking about:

> Lord Voldemort has returned, you have been chasing the wrong **man** for twelve months, and it is time you listened to sense!

> Lord Voldemort has returned, you have been chasing the wrong **men** for twelve months, and it is time you listened to sense!

(emphasis mine)

**What's the story behind this discrepancy?** Is it a difference between British and American editions of the book, or something more complicated? Which editions exactly have which version of the sentence? Which version came first, and when did the other version first appear? Has JKR or any publisher or other official source said anything about *why* it was changed?

Comment: Just above this sentence, Dumbledore says “I am ready to fight your men”. I wonder if the author/editor/whoever might have accidentally taken the word “men” from there.

Comment: Not that it matters, but in my translated version, it says something like: "You've been chasing a man who wasn't guilty for 12 months"; apparently translated from English to French from the original edition published by Bloomsbury Publishing Plc London 2003.

Comment: No mention of this change in https://www.hp-lexicon.org/differences-uk-us-editions-op/ or https://www.hp-lexicon.org/edits-changes-text-op/

Comment: My First Edition UK Bloomsbury edition has "man" (page 721), so I'd say that version almost certainly came first. Mine also has a comma between win and again, unlike the screenshot from the other question.

Comment: Either way, both sentences do make sense. "Man" would apply to Dumbledore, "men" could be Dumbledore and the Death Eaters, or perhaps even Harry.

Comment: In the German ebook it's singular: "...Sie haben zwölf Monate lang **den falschen Mann** gejagt..."  And in the French ebook also: "Lord Voldemort est revenu, vous avez recherché pendant douze mois **un homme** qui n’était pas coupable et il serait temps que vous redeveniez raisonnable !"

Comment: It's a US vs UK difference. I have no more info beyond that though, so not sure if it's worth posting this as an answer.

Comment: @ibid but y tho?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - No idea. There's a bunch of random differences between the two editions that aren't really explained.

Comment: @ibid bad translation/localization?